# Issues setting up deeplab (caffe) - ATLAS Library is missing

Tags: c++, cmake, caffe, atlas, openblas

I am trying to setup deeplab which is build on caffe.
I just have issues with the dependencies - i have downloaded now 
`"atlas3.10.3.tar"` and I have added `"C:\Users\johndoe\Documents\ICNET Project\atlas3.10.3.tar\ATLAS"` as `"Atlas_ROOT_DIR"` to the environment variables.

Nevertheless it shows me following complains:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Atlas (missing: Atlas_CBLAS_LIBRARY Atlas_BLAS_LIBRARY
  Atlas_LAPACK_LIBRARY)
```

Do you know how solve this issue on windows?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to **unpack** archive before library will be usable. Viewing the archive's content in the files browser doesn't mean that files actually exists.

Comment: sure, i have already unpacked the archive which was named "atlas3.10.3.tar.bz2" , the folder name is "atlas3.10.3.tar"

Comment: Normally, `.tar` extension is for *archive* files. Are you sure that it is a directory and not an archive? Note, that double extension `.tar.bz2` means "archive in archive", while some archive managers may unpack it in a single step.